# Visual Basic 2010 Live Logger

Tags: vb.net, logging

Hello I am trying to make a live logger in my program so I can keep track of the progress.
Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmcTp.png

How do I make something like this.

Comment: What sort of work have you tried so far?

Comment: i am asking to make a live log so when I start the progress i can see something like this  Progress Started,Working,Working,Process ended

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

You can use background worker, with a listbox to accomplish what you are asking. On the reports progress method of background worker, you can specify the "userstate" object to "log" to controls on the UI thread, just make sure to set 'worker reports progress' to true:

```
 Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'where you call your worker to do work
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()


End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    'make sure to set worker reports progress to true
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "About to Messagebox") 'where 0 is a progress percent if you want it and the string is overloaded
    MsgBox("This is to show how to report before an event!")


End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    '
    ListBox1.Items.Add(e.UserState)


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you got any video tutorial cant understand it

Comment: youtube is your friend:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv4FdoaUMQE

However, you will not have to use delegates like the guy says in the video, you can use reportsprogress to pass back the values you need.

Comment: how do I add more  BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "About to Messagebox") with more messages

Comment: Just duplicate the report progress and change the string to match what you need it to do? At some point you need to define all the possiblr strings that could or should occur